# clickable prototypes> map every possible pathway?

Tags: mobile, games, prototype, balsamiq

I am building a clickable prototype of a mobile game in balsamic for a client.

Do I have to map every single branch option? If so, the home screen, for example, would have many different states and will all need slightly different return screens depending on what is clicked.

It would be easier not to make every option clickable and just demonstrate one pathway per function. More of an interactive demo or tour I guess. But that isn't a true representation of what the build will be. (the real build will have multiple clickable options for the user).

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: If you want to map out a lot of routes with multiple states for the same screen, maybe coding it will be easier than using a prototyping tool. You can always ask a dev for help. I personally code all my prototypes as it allows me to make it more realistic than any tool would allow.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the purpose of the prototype. If you are going to perform usability tests using the prototype, then you should map multiple paths because you will never know where the user will start to perform a certain task.

Also if the paths are logic or task-based, then you might want to map different paths.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the goal of the prototype. If the goal is to be an exhaustive UI specification for development then I guess you have to do it.

Usually prototypes are just used to illustrate the most important pathways. The developers will put the rest together trying to align with the logic in your prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing a specific feature, you don't need to make the whole prototype clickable - just the areas that you are testing. You can add helper text within the screen if you feel like you need it (eg. put a block of text at the top or bottom of your screen instructing the user what to do next). Usually, the prototype will highlight where the user is supposed to click - although i'm not familiar with how Balsamiq works.

I would recommend using something like Maze (https://maze.design/) or Invision (https://www.invisionapp.com/) for your prototype because it allows you to define multiple paths, add instructions, and get data like heat maps of where your users clicked. I think you can try both for free.